# How to solve $\sin(2x)=\frac{8}{\pi}x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-1$?

Tags: calculus

As part of an exercise, I'm trying to solve the following equation:
$$\sin(2x)=\frac{8}{\pi}x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-1$$

The problem is that I have $x$ on on both sides and I don't know how to continue.

Randomly picking $x$s I found out that $\frac{\pi}{8}$ solves it. But how to show it "formally" (over $\mathbb{R}$)?

Comment: Hint: show that $f-g$ is a decreasing function where $f(x)$ is your left side and $g(x)$ is your right side. (This is an easy thing to show if you have access to using calculus.)

Comment: @alex.jordan Hi, thanks you the comment. How does it help to find $x$?

Comment: You found one solution $x$. If you prove that $f-g$ is decreasing, it can be used to prove there are no other solutions.

As to _how_ you found that one $x$, your approach of checking a few things, especially rational multiples of $\pi$, was good. But there is no systematic method to use on an equation like this. Simply change that $8$ to a $7$ or something, and in general you will not have solutions that are "nice" like rational multiples of $\pi$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly,$$x=\frac\pi8\implies\sin(2x)=\frac8\pi x+\frac1{\sqrt2}-1.$$On the other hand, if$$f(x)=\sin(2x)-\frac8\pi x-\frac1{\sqrt2}+1,$$then$$f'(x)=2\cos(2x)-\frac8\pi<0.$$Therefore, $f$ is strictly decreasing, and so it can have, at most, a single zero. So, $\frac\pi8$ is the only solution of the equation.

Comment: How have you found the solution $x=\dfrac{\pi}8\;?$

Comment: Well, that $\frac8\pi$ looked suspicious…

Comment: Thank you for proving that $\pi/8$ is the only one but I also want to know how to find it (I'm afraid I'll get a similar question in the exam and get stuck figuring the $x$).

Comment: Impressive. Why was it suspicious $\frac 8\pi$? I would have used the bisection method or numerical methods :-(

Comment: @Sebastiano Because if the idea was to *find* a solution, it would have to be a number $x$ such that the value of $\sin(2x)$ was known. There aren't that many numbers. And then $\sin(x)$ is always an algebraic number. But then the $\pi$ from $\frac8\pi x+\frac1{\sqrt2}-1$ would have to disappear. Again, there aren't that many choices.

Comment: @vesii I hope (for you) that you don't think that there is a universal solution for that type of problems.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I have not clear on the meaning *it would have to be a number $x$ such that the value of $\sin(2x)$ was known*. If you put $x=\pi/8$ I get an identity. By algebraic number what do you mean a real number? I not clear also *But then the π from $8π/x+1\sqrt2−1$ would have to disappear.* My congratulations.

Comment: @Sebastiano If $x=1$, or $x=\frac\pi7$, I don't know the value of $\sin(2x)$, but I do know if, say, $x=\frac\pi6$ or $x=\frac\pi8$. And by [algebraic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number) I meant a number which is a root of a non-zero polynomial with rational coefficients. For instance, $\frac1{\sqrt2}$ is an algebraic number, but $\pi$ isn't. So, the $\pi$ from $\frac8\pi x+\frac1{\sqrt2}-1$ would have to vanish for my choice of $x$.

Comment: One way to find it is to use a graphing calculator, or use Newton's method, or something else computational, to work the solution out to many decimal places, to think, to look at it, to wonder, and then if you're lucky to notice that $8$ times that number is $3.14159...$, and then to say to yourself "I wonder if the solution is $\frac{\pi}{8}$", and then to do what this answer does.